# Quadratic Equation not working properly

Tags: c, function

I am new to both this site and C programming and I am attempting to make a quadratic formula but I cannot get the roots to work. I believe I am not calling a function or perhaps there is something else wrong. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float userinput(char prompt[]); //Function Prototype
float root(float a, float b, float c);

int main()
{

    float a,b,c;

    a=userinput("Enter the value for a:"); //Function Call
    b=userinput("Enter the value for b:");
    c=userinput("Enter the value for c:");

    printf("The Equation you entered is |n%fx^2%+fx%+f=0", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}

float root(float a, float b, float c)
{
    float D,x,x1,x2,x3,x4;
    D = b*b - 4*a*c;
    if(D>0)
        {
            printf("There are two real roots, the roots are: ");
            x1 = ((-b+(sqrt(D)))/(2*a));
            x2 = ((-b-(sqrt(D)))/(2*a));
            printf("%.2f and %.2f,x1 , x2");
        }

    if(D==0)
        {
            printf("There is one real root, the root is: ");
            x = ((-b)/(2*a));
            printf("%.2f,x");
        }

    if(D<0)
        {
            printf("There are two imaginary roots. The roots are: ");
            x3 = ((-b/2*a)+(sqrt(fabs(D))/(2*a)));
            printf("%.2f,x3i and");
            x4 = ((-b/2*a)-(sqrt(fabs(D))/(2*a)));
            printf("%.2f,x4i");
        }
}

float userinput(char prompt[]) //Function definition
{
    float answer;
    int status;
    do
        {
            printf("%s",prompt);

            status=scanf("%f", &answer);
            if(status!=1)
                {
                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("INPUT ERROR!\n");
                }
        }
    while(status!=1);

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: `%+f` should be `+%f` in the `printf` format string.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour

Comment: What specifically is wrong with your program? What inputs did you give, what result did you expect, and what did you get instead?

Comment: if I included stdio.h then stdin.h is also included. Therefore it would not be undefined, correct?

Comment: To correctly format your code: 1)  paste the code 2) select the code 3) click the code button which looks like this `{}`.

Comment: What exactly is not working about it?  One thing I notice is that your `printf` statements aren't structured correctly.  The values to be replaced in the `%f` of the formatted string are extra arguments.  For example, `printf("%.2f and %.2f,x1 ,x2");` should be `printf("%.2f and %.2f", x1, x2);`.  See [man printf(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Comment: @Iknownothing `fflush` can only be used on **output** streams, it's not defined for input.

Comment: The problem is that I enter my equation (in the form of ax^2 + bx + c) and it will not calculate the roots for me. So all I am getting is the display of my equation and it tells me it is returning 0.

Comment: There is no return statement in the `root()` function, so why would it return anything?  Also, you never call `root()`.

Comment: ok, how do I call it then because I thought I had done that.

Comment: See my answer below on calling `root()`.  Place it somewhere after you read the values from the user, and before `return 0;` of the `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You never call the function `root()` so it will never be executed.  Put the function call somewhere before `return 0;` of `main()`:

```
    root(a, b, c);
```

Also, fix the `printf()` calls as mentioned above.

Comment: just so I understand clearly, placing it before 'return 0;' allows the code written for finding the roots to be run even though it is below the 'return' statement itself?

Comment: The `return 0;` is the return statement from the `main()` function.  Once this is executed, control leaves the `main()` function (and your program is over).  So this must be the last thing executed in `main()`.  Yes, anything that will be executed must be before this.

Comment: okay, thank you very much to all of you for your help. I was reading a bunch of stuff on functions but you all made it much clearer for me.

Comment: See where the `root(a, b, c)` line is placed in the example code from the answer by @Barmar .  I should have given a more complete example of the corrected code like he did.

Comment: yes, I found that and used it in my code. It was a team effort by all of you.

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning is to consider using `double` instead of `float` for your variables.  See [this post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/188721/when-do-you-use-float-and-when-do-you-use-double) about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix everything but in your code you have your print statements formatted incorrectly. For example, this line:

`printf("%.2f and %.2f,x1 , x2");`

Should be `printf("%.2f and %.2f", x1, x2);`

The variables whose values you are trying to use should be outside of the quotation marks. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors.

1. You never call `root()`.
2. `root` is declared to return `float`, but it doesn't return anything, it just prints the roots. It should be declared `void`.
3. You have mistakes in many of your `printf()` calls. When you're displaying the equation, you have `|n` instead of `\n`, and `%+f` instead of `+%f`. When you're displaying the roots, you have the variables that you want to print inside the format string, instead of as separate arguments to `printf`.

Here's the corrected code.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float userinput(char prompt[]); //Function Prototype
void root(float a, float b, float c);

int main()
{

    float a,b,c;

    a=userinput("Enter the value for a:"); //Function Call
    b=userinput("Enter the value for b:");
    c=userinput("Enter the value for c:");

    printf("The Equation you entered is \n%fx^2+%fx+%f=0\n", a, b, c);
    root(a, b, c);
    return 0;
}

void root(float a, float b, float c)
{
    float D,x,x1,x2,x3,x4;
    D = b*b - 4*a*c;
    if(D>0)
        {
            printf("There are two real roots, the roots are: ");
            x1 = ((-b+(sqrt(D)))/(2*a));
            x2 = ((-b-(sqrt(D)))/(2*a));
            printf("%.2f and %.2f" ,x1 , x2);
        }

    if(D==0)
        {
            printf("There is one real root, the root is: ");
            x = ((-b)/(2*a));
            printf("%.2f",x);
        }

    if(D<0)
        {
            printf("There are two imaginary roots. The roots are: ");
            x3 = ((-b/2*a)+(sqrt(fabs(D))/(2*a)));
            printf("%.2fi and ", x3);
            x4 = ((-b/2*a)-(sqrt(fabs(D))/(2*a)));
            printf("%.2fi", x4);
        }
}

float userinput(char prompt[]) //Function definition
{
    float answer;
    int status;
    do
        {
            printf("%s",prompt);

            status=scanf("%f", &answer);
            if(status!=1)
                {
                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("INPUT ERROR!\n");
                }
        }
    while(status!=1);

    return answer;
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/q1KvuN)